# Javafx continuously rotate object using mouse drag to accelerate

Tags: animation, javafx, 3d, rotation, javafx-8

I have a project i'm trying to develop controls for. I need to be able to continuously rotate the object from a single mouse click and drag and release. After releasing I wish the object to continue rotating from its initial point to the position where i released the mouse.(provided the object has not already reached this position.) I've seen applications previously that worked in this manner and I cant seem to find any code online to show how that was implemented. I am using this below code to test my mouse controls before adding them to my project. It contains simple drag and release mechanics already. However I would appreciate some input as to how to go about adding the continuous rotation. I want the mouse to be able to control the speed of the rotation of the object along any axis. As i have it set up it rotates along any axis. But I would like a drag to instead of rotate the object, cause the object to spin(recursively rotate) at a velocity proportional to distance the mouse was dragged. This would increase velocity as distance increased. If I drag the same direction twice the same distance, the velocity should double, the object then rotating twice as fast.

```
package javafxapplication3;



import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.geometry.Point3D;
import javafx.scene.DepthTest;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.PhongMaterial;
import javafx.scene.shape.Box;
import javafx.scene.shape.Sphere;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.scene.transform.Transform;
import javafx.scene.transform.Translate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class trafo extends Application {
    final Group root = new Group();
    final XformWorld world = new XformWorld();
    final PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);
    final XformCamera cameraXform = new XformCamera();
    private static final double CAMERA_INITIAL_DISTANCE = -1000;
    private static final double CAMERA_NEAR_CLIP = 0.1;
    private static final double CAMERA_FAR_CLIP = 10000.0;
    double mousePosX, mousePosY, mouseOldX, mouseOldY, mouseDeltaX, mouseDeltaY;
    double mouseFactorX, mouseFactorY;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        root.getChildren().add(world);
        root.setDepthTest(DepthTest.ENABLE);
        buildCamera();
        buildBodySystem();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600, true);
        scene.setFill(Color.GREY);
        handleMouse(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("TrafoTest");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        scene.setCamera(camera);
        mouseFactorX = 180.0 / scene.getWidth();
        mouseFactorY = 180.0 / scene.getHeight();
    }

    private void buildCamera() {
        root.getChildren().add(cameraXform);
        cameraXform.getChildren().add(camera);
        camera.setNearClip(CAMERA_NEAR_CLIP);
        camera.setFarClip(CAMERA_FAR_CLIP);
        camera.setTranslateZ(CAMERA_INITIAL_DISTANCE);
    }

    private void buildBodySystem() {
        PhongMaterial whiteMaterial = new PhongMaterial();
        whiteMaterial.setDiffuseColor(Color.WHITE);
        whiteMaterial.setSpecularColor(Color.LIGHTBLUE);
        Box box = new Box(400, 200, 100);
        box.setMaterial(whiteMaterial);
        PhongMaterial redMaterial = new PhongMaterial();
        redMaterial.setDiffuseColor(Color.DARKRED);
        redMaterial.setSpecularColor(Color.RED);
        Sphere sphere = new Sphere(5);
        sphere.setMaterial(redMaterial);
        sphere.setTranslateX(200.0);
        sphere.setTranslateY(-100.0);
        sphere.setTranslateZ(-50.0);
        world.getChildren().addAll(box);
        world.getChildren().addAll(sphere);
    }

    private void handleMouse(Scene scene) {
        scene.setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent me) -> {
            mousePosX = me.getSceneX();
            mousePosY = me.getSceneY();
            mouseOldX = me.getSceneX();
            mouseOldY = me.getSceneY();
        });
        scene.setOnMouseDragged((MouseEvent me) -> {
            mouseOldX = mousePosX;
            mouseOldY = mousePosY;
            mousePosX = me.getSceneX();
            mousePosY = me.getSceneY();
            mouseDeltaX = (mousePosX - mouseOldX);
            mouseDeltaY = (mousePosY - mouseOldY);
            if (me.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                cameraXform.ry(mouseDeltaX * 180.0 / scene.getWidth());
                cameraXform.rx(-mouseDeltaY * 180.0 / scene.getHeight());
            } else if (me.isSecondaryButtonDown()) {
                camera.setTranslateZ(camera.getTranslateZ() + mouseDeltaY);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}

class XformWorld extends Group {
    final Translate t = new Translate(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    final Rotate rx = new Rotate(0, 0, 0, 0, Rotate.X_AXIS);
    final Rotate ry = new Rotate(0, 0, 0, 0, Rotate.Y_AXIS);
    final Rotate rz = new Rotate(0, 0, 0, 0, Rotate.Z_AXIS);

    public XformWorld() {
        super();
        this.getTransforms().addAll(t, rx, ry, rz);
    }
}

class XformCamera extends Group {
    Point3D px = new Point3D(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    Point3D py = new Point3D(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    Rotate r;
    Transform t = new Rotate();

    public XformCamera() {
        super();
    }

    public void rx(double angle) {
        r = new Rotate(angle, px);
        this.t = t.createConcatenation(r);
        this.getTransforms().clear();
        this.getTransforms().addAll(t);
    }

    public void ry(double angle) {
        r = new Rotate(angle, py);
        this.t = t.createConcatenation(r);
        this.getTransforms().clear();
        this.getTransforms().addAll(t);
    }

}
```

Comment: "*After releasing I wish the object to continue rotating from its initial point to the position where i released the mouse.*" What does that mean? Maybe give an example.

Comment: To clarify, I would like something similar to google earth's rotation: google.com/earth only I want the rotation to continue at the same speed as when I let go of the mouse. I suppose what I mean is I would like a velocity of rotation. Perhaps this would be as simple as initiating a recursive call to a my rotate_x and rotate_y functions in response to a mouse released event? I need a velocity of rotation calculated. This should be base off of the speed at which I drag, but also the immediacy of me letting go of the mouse. So that the image has not caught up to it @user1803551

Comment: "*I need a velocity of rotation calculated. This should be base off of the speed at which I drag, but also the immediacy of me letting go of the mouse.*" And what is that calculation? We can't tell you what you want. You have to be specific about how you want it to work. [Edit] your question with the relevant details.

Comment: @user1803551 is that edit more helpful? I believe it velocity could be calculated the same way my mouseDelta_X and mouseDelta_Y are calculated.

Comment: So when you drag the mouse, before releasing, nothing happens? Only on release will the object start to rotate?

Answer (score -1):

So the way I see it, you want to calculate the arc that the drag made from the middle of the object that you want to rotate, and rotate the whenever that object is not rotated correctly, it will rotate at a constants speed until it reaches the desired rotation. I've never done something like that, so I don't know if my answer will actually work, but I can at least try, because I think I know the solution. Now the code below may or may not work, please tell me if anything is not correct, I'll try to fix it.

```
public class RotationNode extends Pane {

    double startMouseAngle, goalAngle = 0.0, angleBeforeRotation;
    boolean currentlyRotating = false;

    public RotationNode(double angle) {
        //Parameter angle is to give this Pane a start angle if you want to
        super();

        //This can all change to whatever you want it to be
        setTranslateX(400.0);
        setTranslateY(200.0);
        setPrefSize(100.0, 100.0);
        setRotationAxis(new Point3D(0.0, 0.0, 360.0));

        //This is just to show something is actually rotating
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
        r.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        getChildren().add(r);

        setRotate(angle);
        angleBeforeRotation = 0.0;

        addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, ov -> {
            if(ov.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
                double x = ov.getX();
                double y = ov.getY();
                startMouseAngle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(x, y));
                angleBeforeRotation = currentlyRotating ? goalAngle : getRotate();
                ov.consume();
            }
        });

        addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, ov -> {
            if(ov.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
                double x = ov.getX();
                double y = ov.getY();
                double a = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(x, y));
                double deltaAngle = startMouseAngle - a;
                goalAngle = angleBeforeRotation + deltaAngle;
                if(!currentlyRotating) {
                    new changeRotation();
                }
                ov.consume();
            }
        });
    }

    private class changeRotation {

        private final long TIME_STEP = 25;

        private final double ANGLE_PER_SECOND = 90;
        public changeRotation() {
            final ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

            Runnable changeWidthCmd = () -> {
                double rotationDelta = ANGLE_PER_SECOND / (1000.0 / TIME_STEP);
                rotationDelta *= getRotate() > goalAngle ? -1 : 1;
                setRotate(getRotate() + rotationDelta);
                if(getRotate() - goalAngle < ANGLE_PER_SECOND / (1000.0 / TIME_STEP) && getRotate() - goalAngle > -ANGLE_PER_SECOND / (1000.0 / TIME_STEP)) {
                    setRotate(goalAngle);
                    currentlyRotating = false;
                    service.shutdown();
                }
            };

            currentlyRotating = true;
            service.scheduleAtFixedRate(changeWidthCmd, 0, TIME_STEP, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you,

Lenardjee

EDIT :
Updated the code, it now works kind of. The rotation based on mouse drag works, but the centre point is weird and doesn't work that well. I will try try to improve this and update this answer

**IMPORTANT EDIT :**
I forgot to mention that this answer contains code that uses an external library. To add it, add this to the projects pom file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.reactivex.rxjava2</groupId>
        <artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.14</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

or download the library from
https://jar-download.com/?detail_search=g%3A%22io.reactivex.rxjava2%22&g=io.reactivex.rxjava2&p=1
and add that jar to the projects dependencies.

Comment: To clarify, I would like something similar to google earth's rotation: https://www.google.com/earth/ only I want the rotation to continue at the same speed as when I let go of the mouse. I suppose what I mean is I would like a velocity of rotation.  Perhaps this would be as simple as initiating a recursive call to a my rotate_x and rotate_y functions in response to a mouse released event? I need a velocity of rotation calculated. This should be base off of the speed at which I drag, but also the immediacy of me letting go of the mouse. So that the image has not caught up to it.

Comment: so you want to let the object gain rotational velocity by moving the mouse, and as long as the mouse is dragging, the velocity will immediately adapt to the mouse movement speed, but as soon as the mouse releases, the objects rotational velocity will decrease till it's zero. I think I can make that for you, but it'll take some time. By the way, is it a two dimensional object or is it a three dimensional object?

Comment: Yes, and thank you for your response. You almost have it, I want the speed to continue and not decrease unless dragged the opposite direction. When the mouse is released it should continue along its path at the same velocity until again acted upon by the mouse. Its a 3D object. However I think I can find a solution. I was only hoping there was an easier way of doing it. Perhaps using javafx animation and duration. However I can create velocity variables and then use the mouse to accelerate/decelerate the velocity.

Comment: I suppose this means I will need to have a "spin mode" where a mouse drag can alter the velocity in addition to the already created controls. I may make a button for spin mode. Then It may be easiest to just create a recursive function while in spin mode that has parameter for any further changes in velocity or direction. @Lenard

Comment: This is how i would do it if I were doing this in OpenGL

Comment: Yes, I think that is how you should do it. I would use an eventhandler that handles the mouse dragged event and another one that handles the mouse pressed event. In the mouse pressed event, you get the current time in millis, and write it to a field. Then in the mouse dragged event, get the current time in millis and subtract the value of the field from it, that gives you the time between click and drag. Then get the movement and calculate the angle like I did. Calculate the anle per second, and apply the code that I wrote for executing at an interval.

Comment: Then you just make sure that angle per second is not a final value, and change it to the value that was calculated. When working with the ScheduledExecuterService, make sure to shut it down using ScheduledExecuterService#shutdown() and if you exit the project before it has stopped, stop the java process manually from the task manager.